# MongoDB lookup and unwind

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to perform a look up which works fine and in the correct document as 'metrics'. The lookup document has an array inside of its object called 'history'. I'm trying to unwind that history and perform a facet on it, an aggregation query that I have directly on the lookup collection that works fine.

However when using it here it's not returning anything. Am I unwinding this incorrectly? should it be `$metrics.history` ?

```
{
  from: 'historicprices',
  localField: 'collectibleId',
  foreignField: 'collectibleId',
  pipeline: [
    {$set: {"target-date": "$$NOW"}}, 
    {$unwind: {path: "$history"}}, 
    {$facet: {
        "one_day": [
            { $match: { $expr: { $lte: [{$subtract: ["$target-date", "$history.date" ]}, {$multiply: [24,60,60,1000] }] } } },
            { $group: { _id: null, "first": { $first: "$history.value" }, "last": { $last: "$history.value" }, "min-price": {"$min": "$history.value"}, "max-price": {"$max": "$history.value"} } },
            { $unset: ["_id"]}
        ]
        "one_week": [
             { $match: { $expr: { $lte: [{$subtract: ["$target-date", "$history.date" ]}, {$multiply: [7, 24, 60, 60, 1000] }] } } },
             { $group: { _id: null, "min-price": {"$min": "$history.value"}, "first": { $first: "$history.value" }, "last": { $last: "$history.value" }, "max-price": {"$max": "$history.value"} } },
             { $unset: ["_id"]}
        ]
    }}
  ],
  as: 'metrics',
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` to your unwind stage. Otherwise no data will be received if one of the docs doesn't return this field.